# REST API for Firebase Crashlytics?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

I'm seeing documentation about a REST API for Firebase, but not specifically for Crashlytics. Is there a way to pull my crashlytics data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can export your Crashlytics data into [BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export?authuser=0) for further analysis. BigQuery allows you to analyze the data using BigQuery SQL, export it to another cloud provider, and use it for visualization and custom dashboards with Google Data Studio.

You can stream your Crashlytics data in realtime with [BigQueryStreaming](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export?authuser=0#streaming-export). You can use it for any purpose that requires live data, such as presenting information in a live dashboard, watching a rollout live, or monitoring application problems that trigger alerts and custom workflows.

Crashlytics BigQuery streaming export is not available for BigQuery sandbox.

Comment: Thanks - Big Query Streaming is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: thanks for pointing it out SSO linked - I just updated the links. You should be able to click/edit

Comment: As i understand the data is exported to BigQuery once per day. This is not suitable for my needs. What i need is to integrate a check into a Jenkins pipeline which verifies that there are no reported crashes for a particular Android app which are nothandled by the team (not resolved). Is there a way to do that?