Display crashlytics in the application using Firebase
I need to display crashlytics in the application users using Firebase.
I understand how to bind Crashlytics to the application and receive data in the Firebase console. But how can you make crash statistics appear in the application?
I don't know where to dig. I linked Crashlytics to the application, force crash and see the analytics.

heyy look at this you will have to use BigQuery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61883874/rest-api-for-firebase-crashlytics
